# Foxit Reader on Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Tags: foxitreader

So, "Foxit Reader on Ubuntu Mate 18.04."
Downloaded. Installed. Reported so by Mate Terminal.
I can find Foxit as some fancy pictures in programs.
But I cannot open any PDF book by Foxit as default. 
(Just like Libre Office Writer works for my files.)
Could anybody, please, gimme the link my question is answered by "sudo..."? Thank you. Igor

Comment: I tried another way, following this link: https://linuxhint.com/install_foxit_reader_ubuntu/ . That worked fine. I got Foxit full package, even "for Linux 64!" Until "Staring Foxit Reader." Foxit didn't get into Ubuntu Mate Applications. So, dead end again.

Comment: I tried again https://www.itsmarttricks.com/how-to-install-foxit-pdf-reader-in-ubuntu-18-04/. This time the result is much better, as every step recommended in this link was preceded by "sudo." Foxit Reader best reads facsimile of old books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system I installed it with commands below:

```
wget http://cdn09.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/linux/2.x/2.4/en_us/FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.4.0911.x64.run.tar.gz
tar -xf FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.4.0911.x64.run.tar.gz
./FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.4.0911\(r057d814\).x64.run
```

and itemphasized text was installed into `/home/user/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader` with the *.desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications/FoxitReader.desktop` and show icon in the MATE Menu and on desktop:

> [image: Foxit reader on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]

and of course it launches and can open PDF files. It set itself as default PDF viewer application.

If it does not to default on your system - then try to use *Open With Other Application ...* from Caja and set Foxit Reader here.

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate your responding.
I managed to install Foxit Reader via https://www.itsmarttricks.com/how-to-install-foxit-pdf-reader-in-ubuntu-18-04/. Got it on Menu. Opened PDF files by Foxit. OK, but I couldn't recognize Foxit I had on Windows 7.
However new to Linux, I dare say that Foxit doesn't belong here. Why? At least because it's not listed in Synaptic PM, whereas Okular & Evince are. 
So, I installed Evince, made it default, and that's it. 
The matter is over. Thanks again, Igor.